Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\Account 2\Documents\source\edc-serial-port\node_modules\@serialport\stream\dist'
please help me on this issue
"Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\Account 2\Documents\source\edc-serial-port\node_modules@serialport\stream\dist'"
i'm currently using Angular17 and cannot compile the solution due to error above. Is there any ways to resolve it?
I want to connect EDC terminal using serialport.
